# iTMSTransporter: "Could not find or load main class" when launched

Tags: java, xcode, macos

I'm trying to notarize a DMG via "xcrun altool" in Terminal but it fails with the output below.

In fact it even running iTMSTransporter directly it crashes:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
Error: Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
```

What I have done to troublehshoot:

- Updated to Xcode 12.3
- Updated and installed latest commandline tools for Xcode
- Tried two different SDK/JDK/JRE versions of Java, currently using java 15.0.1 2020-10-20
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
- Tried declaring JAVA_HOME
- Looked for iTMSTransporter cache file or folder (in case sensitive and lowercase) in /, ~/ and /Library and ~/Library ~/.itmstransporter in order ot delete it, there is none.
- I'm on macOS Big Sur 11.1
- I have never had two name versions of Xcode, so I have not had a different name for the app. I tried renaming it for troubleshooting and reverting back to original Xcode name but this also did not help.
- Tried reinstalling iTMSTransporter

Error output below:

```
2020-12-24 10:39:03.442 altool[10776:511525] Sending request to iTunesTransporter…
2020-12-24 10:39:03.442 altool[10776:511525]     Command: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
2020-12-24 10:39:03.442 altool[10776:511525]   Arguments: -m upload -u 'XXX' -vp json -DTxHeaders=XXX= -sessionid @env:XXX -sharedsecret @env:XXX -itc_provider '-f' -f '/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/XXX-72174C6DE294/com.XXX.XXX.itmsp' -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client='altool' -Dtransporter.client.version='4.029 (1194)'
2020-12-24 10:39:04.331 altool[10776:511518] Error: Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
2020-12-24 10:39:04.331 altool[10776:511518] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
2020-12-24 10:39:04.336 altool[10776:511525]  Error:
Error: Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.
2020-12-24 10:39:04.336 altool[10776:511525]  Out:
2020-12-24 10:39:04.337 altool[10776:511525] Errors: (
    "Error Domain=ITunesTransporterErrorDomain Code=-18000 \"Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:., NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.}"
)
2020-12-24 10:39:04.378 altool[10776:511518] *** Error: Unable to notarize app.
2020-12-24 10:39:04.378 altool[10776:511518] *** Error: code -18000 (Could not find or load main class 1.Library.Java.Extensions:.Library.Java.Extensions:.Network.Library.Java.Extensions:.System.Library.Java.Extensions:.usr.lib.java:.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed after commenting out the line starting with:
JVM_LIB_PATH

in:
/usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter

It seems the way this line was setting the java related paths to iTMSTransporter was causing it to look in wrong places.

After commenting out this line iTMSTransporter reconfigured itself during launch and notarization submission was successful.